# 10gig link transfer speed slow between dell chassis m1000e blades

Tags: networking, centos7, dell, ssd, 10gige

I have a dell chassis m1000e. All blades are connected internally with Dellm8024 10gbit switch.

I've SSD on blades. However, when i am testing the speed between the blades the maximum speed size is 120 MBp/s. I even cant get near 10 Gbit speed. I tried to configure manually MTU but had no luck.

What would be the possible reason for this low speed? Any ideas for troubleshooting?

Regards,
Qasim Azam

Comment: Can you test performance using a tool such as iperf3? What link speed is shown in the OS? 120Mb/s *sounds* suspiciously close to 1Gb/s...

Comment: 120MB/s is 1Gbps. What's your NIC in your blades? What's the negotiated speed in the NIC?

Comment: With 10 Gbp/s NIC you should be able to reach at least about 9 Gb/s even with standard 1500 MTU. Some useful commannds:
iperf (for performance test)
ifconfig -a (to see all network intarfaces, maybe you have more than one and use a slow 1 Gb/s interface)

dmesg | grep eth (to see information about network interfaces in the log)

ethtool (to show things like link speed for different interfaces)

Comment: [This Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/207474/how-do-i-verify-the-speed-of-my-nic) may be useful for checking the link speed and capabilities of the cards.