# How can I run a script whenever my NIC Link speed drops?

Tags: networking

I'm having issues with my ethernet dropping down from 10 GbE to 1 GbE and even sometimes down to 100 Mbps.

1. I would like to receive a notification when this happens through something like healthchecks.io or email.
2. I would like to toggle the port down and up again to try and force it to reconnect at 10 GbE speeds.

This is on an unraid machine.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I verify the speed of my NIC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/207474/how-do-i-verify-the-speed-of-my-nic)

Comment: That would depend on what is managing the network interfaces on your system. This varies by OS and version. Without further information this can't be answered.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider as above its unraid. 6.9.2 to be precise.

Comment: You should check/fix your cable.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question and this is not a cable issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that changing link speed triggers a udev event or something similar, but the first solution that comes to my mind is scheduling a shell script with the [User Scripts plugin](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/48286-plugin-ca-user-scripts/). You can monitor the link speed of an interface with `ethtool`, so I wrote a quick script to check the speed that i tested on my 6.11.5 unraid box.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFACE=eth0
SPEED=$(ethtool $IFACE | grep Speed | awk '{print $2}')

if [ $SPEED = "10000Mb/s" ]; then
    echo Correct Speed
else
    echo Incorrect speed
fi
```

You'll need to find a command that notifies you in a way that you like, maybe calling `curl` on with some web API would do the trick. This example works for gigabit, but if you want to use it for any other speed it'll need to be updated with the speed you're interested in.

To try resetting the interface you could try something like `ip link set $IFACE down; ip link set $IFACE up`, but I have no idea if that would do anything. Maybe you could wait until the issue pops up and then type that in by hand to try it.

Comment: Thanks this is great and for the record it says "10000Mb/s".